# What does RectTransform.GetWorldCorners() do under the hood? Is it expensive?

Tags: unity-game-engine

What does Unity 2D UI method [RectTransform.GetWorldCorners()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.GetWorldCorners.html) do under the hood? I am worried about it being expensive. Does it use Raycasting to find the world corners?

FYI: I am using a canvas with render mode "Screen Space - Camera"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I inspected the source code generated by my IDE, and `RectTransform.GetWorldCorners()` is not performing any raycasting. These are the steps it executes to get the world corners.

1. Calls `RectTransform.GetLocalCorners()` and gets the local corners from `RectTransform.rect`.
2. Each of the local corner points are multiplied with `transform.localToWorldMatrix` matrix.

So apparently the method is relatively **inexpensive** to use, but always cache the result until you make any changes to the `RectTransform`.